# Prevent Application Bar from scrolling up Layout

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am building a windows phone 8 application with an `ApplicationBar` to keep the shortcuts and some menu options for the application. I read somewhere that that `Height` for `ApplicationBar` is 72px. So I tried with this code

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="72"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Name="scrollViewer" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="DarkSeaGreen">
                <TextBlock Name="tb" FontSize="100" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="Hello eveyone. Need some help with AppBar">
                </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I was expecting the ApplicationBar to fit in space provided in the `Grid` and not to scroll up my layout. But what happened is this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjEXD.png

ApplicationBar pushed up the Layout leaving a blank space. I wish to prevent this thing. I want my Application Bar to be visible but it should not scroll up my layout. Please help if you know of any kind of solution to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the `Opacity` of your ApplicationBar to a value < 1. Then it overlays your layout and does not push it up. In my eyes `Opacity="0.99"` is a good option.

**But be careful**: The ApplicationBar's height is not always 72px. On a 1080p device for example it differs!

To determine the actual height of your Application Bar you can use `ApplicationBar.DefaultSize` or respectively `ApplicationBar.MiniSize`.

For more information the the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar).

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot about Opacity. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi. Is there some way to determine height of `ApplicationBar` from code

Comment: Yes, you can get the height of your `ApplicationBar` via code. I updated my answer for that. And yes, this actually has to work in the emulator, too.