# ApplicationBar scrolls up layout with opacity set

Tags: windows-phone-8

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339018/prevent-application-bar-from-scrolling-up-layout) earlier. With ApplicationBar visible, it scrolls up my complete layout to fit in. When I set `ApplicationBar.Opacity = 0.99;` it worked fine on phone. But later on when I tested it on emulator, problem persists. It is still working on my testing handset.

I noticed that my **emulator OS version is 8.0.9903.10** and **phone OS version is 8.0.10517.150**. Is this the reason? Will it not work on newer OS versions? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the color you are giving to the ApplicationBar?
Are you giving the color to the ApplicationBar before or after setting the Opacity.
If the BackgroundColor of the ApplicationBar has no transparency and is set after the Opacity property it can override it.

Comment: I am setting it after setting Opacity. But how does it matter? Opacity and Color should be independent of eachother.

Comment: @AndréMeneses I have given it a Color using Color.FromArgb. And how can I set transparency of a Color. I found no such option.

Comment: `Color.FromArgb(254, 255, 255, 255);` (for example)
The First value (a or alpha) is the opacity value